# How to pass data from return activity to dialog in previous activity?

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, material-dialog

Visitor Details

I have a dialog in Visitor Activity. When I click on the icon, it will redirect to Camera Activity. Then when click Confirm button in Camera Activity, it will send the intent back to previous Activity which is Visitor Activity. The problem is how should I pass the intent result from Camera Activity back to the dialog in Visitor Activity. The intent data should be placed in the Pass No Edit Text. I'm using material dialog without any Fragment that attached to that dialog. It all placed in Visitor Activity. Can someone please help me? Thank you!

```
private void checkin()
{
    final MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(VisitorDetailActivity.this)
            .customView(R.layout.sample,false)
            .build();

    View view = dialog.getCustomView();
    final EditText etPassNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassNo);
    final EditText etVehicleNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etVehicleNo);
    final ImageView ivScanCode = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivScanCode);
    final TextView tvCancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);
    final TextView tvSubmit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubmit);

    etVehicleNo.setText(model.getFldVehicleNo());

    if(barCode != null)
    {
        etPassNo.setText(barCode);
    }

    ivScanCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(VisitorDetailActivity.this, "Bar code scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(VisitorDetailActivity.this, ScanCodeActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i,97);
        }
    });

    tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    tvSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(etPassNo.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(VisitorDetailActivity.this, "Pass No is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(selImage == null)
            {
                proceedCheckin(etPassNo.getText().toString(), etVehicleNo.getText().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                proceedCheckinImage(etPassNo.getText().toString(), etVehicleNo.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 98 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        selImage = data.getStringExtra("photo");

        Glide.with(VisitorDetailActivity.this).load(selImage).into(iDrivingLicense);

    }
    else if (requestCode == 99 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        selImage = data.getStringExtra("photo");

        Glide.with(VisitorDetailActivity.this).load(selImage).into(iDrivingLicense);
    }
    else if(requestCode == 97 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        barCode = data.getStringExtra("barCode");
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to take the view object globally out of that `checkIn` methoed

```
View view;
view = dialog.getCustomView();
final EditText etPassNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassNo);
```

Now under your `onActivityResult` method, as i can see you already getting the barcode there, so just initiate the EditText object again on that same simply set the data in it.

```
barCode = data.getStringExtra("barCode");
EditText etPassNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassNo); 
etPassNo.setText(barCode);
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using interface

```
public interface OnBarcodeSelect{
    void onBarcodeSelected(String barcode);}
OnBarcodeSelect onBarcodeSelect;
private void checkin()
{
    final MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(VisitorDetailActivity.this)
            .customView(R.layout.sample,false)
            .build();

    View view = dialog.getCustomView();
    final EditText etPassNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etPassNo);
    final EditText etVehicleNo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etVehicleNo);
    final ImageView ivScanCode = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivScanCode);
    final TextView tvCancel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);
    final TextView tvSubmit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubmit);

    etVehicleNo.setText(model.getFldVehicleNo());

    if(barCode != null)
    {
        etPassNo.setText(barCode);
    }

    ivScanCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(VisitorDetailActivity.this, "Bar code scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(VisitorDetailActivity.this, ScanCodeActivity.class);
            onBarcodeSelect = new OnBarcodeSelect() {
                @Override
                public void onBarcodeSelected(String barcode) {
                    //handle barcode here
                    etPassNo.setText(barcode);
                }
            }
            startActivityForResult(i,97);
        }
    });

    tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    tvSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(etPassNo.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
            {
                Toast.makeText(VisitorDetailActivity.this, "Pass No is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(selImage == null)
            {
                proceedCheckin(etPassNo.getText().toString(), etVehicleNo.getText().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                proceedCheckinImage(etPassNo.getText().toString(), etVehicleNo.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 98 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        selImage = data.getStringExtra("photo");

        Glide.with(VisitorDetailActivity.this).load(selImage).into(iDrivingLicense);

    }
    else if (requestCode == 99 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        selImage = data.getStringExtra("photo");

        Glide.with(VisitorDetailActivity.this).load(selImage).into(iDrivingLicense);
    }
    else if(requestCode == 97 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        barCode = data.getStringExtra("barCode");
        if(onBarcodeSelect != null){
            onBarcodeSelect.onBarcodeSelected(barCode);
        }
    }
}
```